# How can I remove the data in array have used group_by method in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to remove the value of data have been `group_by`, because the object `@deals`

I need to arrange the data by date.

But, the problems is that I used iteration of `@period` and the value in the `@deals` would be calculated once again.It's not efficient and I tried to use `map` method to slice the data as following:

```
@period = Date.new(2019,3,1)..Date.new(2019,3,31)
@deals = Deal.where(created_at: @period).includes(:staff).group_by{|t| t.staff}

@period.each do |date|
 @deals.map do |staff, deals|
  puts "staff:#{staff.name}"
  puts deals.count
  selected_deals = deals.select{|t| Date.parse(t.created_at) == date}
  puts selected_deals.select{|t| t.deal_product=="item1"}.count
  puts selected_deals.select{|t| t.deal_product=="item2"}.count
  puts selected_deals.select{|t| t.deal_product=="item3"}.count
  puts selected_deals.select{|t| t.deal_product=="item4"}.count
  deals-selected_deals
 end
end
```

but it's seen not remove the data I have selected.

It's possibile to do what I want?

Answer (score 0):

`.select` doesn't change data in place, but returns a new value, so does `.map`. Try `@period.map` and assign whole expression to a variable.

```
@data = @period.map do |date|
  @deals.map do |staff, deals|
    selected_deals = deals.select{|t| t.created_at.to_date == date}
    deals - selected_deals
  end
end
```

If you want to reject values from array, use `.reject`.

```
@data = @period.map do |date|
  @deals.map do |staff, deals|
    deals.reject{|t| t.created_at.to_date == date}
  end
end
```

Comment: I put `puts "staff:#{staff.name} "` and `puts deals.count`in the `@deals` nested structure and read the log in my console, the data still not change...

Comment: Is it possibile to render every date and let `@deals` nested structure wrap up `@period`?

Comment: That the output like the demo https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55466845/how-to-render-the-data-distribute-by-two-attribute-more-efficiently-in-rails